# Configuration Options for Whitespace rules for tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

Is there any way to configure `tslint` to expect whitespaces in usual cases, but specifically warn for whitespaces in `check-module` (example: import) cases.
We have some inconsistencies because different tools generate/copy with different spacing.

```
import {ComponentFixture} from "@angular/core/testing";   
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";           // <-- Based on what I want to configure, this should generate white-space warning
```

I am not sure if this is clear enough, let me try to show the idea with config if that makes any sense:

Is there something like this (`tslint.config`):

```
"whitespace": [
  true,
  "check-branch",
  "check-decl",
  "check-operator",
  "check-separator",
  "check-type"
],
"whitespace": [
  false,
  "check-module"
],
```

I am sure I am not the first to face this problem. Any reference/hint would be helpful.

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/whitespace/

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: @comeback4you I ended up using [prettier](https://prettier.io) instead of tslint for this kind of rules. Sorry about the completely unrelated solution, but I couldn't find a way to do this with tslint :/